# Use single Dockerfile for python based development and production environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using `Dockerfile` to create development environment as well as used in production build.

The project's dependencies are separated in two environment files

```
requirements.txt            -> for production
requirements.dev.txt        -> for development
```

And the contents are

*requirements.txt*

```
package1==1.0.0
package2==1.0.1
```

*requirements.dev.txt*

```
-r requirements.txt
dev-package1==1.0.0
dev-package2==1.0.1
```

And there are two Dockerfile with the identical content, but only the `COPY requirements.txt` statement is changed

***Dockerfile*** (used in production)

```
FROM python:3.9.11-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN set -ex \
    && RUN_DEPS=" \
    libpcre3 \
    mime-support \
    " \
    && seq 1 8 | xargs -I{} mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man{} \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $RUN_DEPS \
    && python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Copy in your requirements file
COPY requirements.txt 

RUN set -ex \
    && BUILD_DEPS=" \
    build-essential \
    libpcre3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    " \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $BUILD_DEPS \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false $BUILD_DEPS \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./src /app/

WORKDIR /app/

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

***Dockerfile.dev*** (for development)

```
< Identical content >

# Copy in your requirements file
COPY requirements.dev.txt 

<Identical content >
```

Now it is difficult to manage exact two copies of **Dockerfile** whenever there is a change during development.

**How can I set my `Dockerfile` to install the respective dependency, depending on the environment, instead of using two separate Dockerfiles?**

Comment: If your development environment will be substantially different from your production environment already, is there any reason it must be in a container; or can you use a more convenient Python virtual environment without Docker instead?

Comment: there are many system dependencies required for the project (removed from above code snippet) it’s a hassle to setup development system of 15+ developers and install all system dependencies manually for the project to work. Also the operating system is not homogeneous. Using docker in development environment makes it easy to install all dependencies in one go, without worrying of host operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the requirements.txt you should instead use a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/) that you pass to the docker command, ie:

In your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG DEPENDENCY_FILE
COPY ${DEPENDENCY_FILE} .
```

and build the image with

```
docker build -t foo --build-arg="DEPENDENCY_FILE=requirements.txt" .
```

I hope it helps :)